# Android Camera preview not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-camera

I found a tutorial online [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm) both for capturing images, they are very similar and I used one another to figure out why my Camera code isn't working.

I do not get any syntax errors in Android but when I go on the desired fragment it is just a white screen, there is no camera display and I have no idea why I have looked at both code examples in depth and googled my problem but cant find anything. The only difference with my code is that its a fragment instead of an activity. Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
public class Image extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private ImageView imageView;
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private Bitmap capturedImage;


//Camera

private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private Parameters parameters;

/**********************************************/

public Image() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_activity, container, false);

    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

    //Get a surface
    sHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();

    //add the callback interface methods defined below as the Surface View callbacks
    sHolder.addCallback(this);

    //tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly replaced
    sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw the preview.

    mCamera = Camera.open();
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {


    //get camera parameters
    parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

    parameters.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
    //set camera parameters
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();

    //sets what code should be executed after the picture is taken
    Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap
            capturedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            String filename= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "testimage.jpg";
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                capturedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //set the iv_image
            imageView.setImageBitmap(capturedImage);
        }
    };

    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
  }
}
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_width="0dip">

</SurfaceView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView">

</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Update 1:

Here is my manifest file, I forgot to include this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I have also enabled the permissions in marshmallow settings for the application but still doesn't show anything

Update 2:
Just tried it with a API 17 device and there is still no preview

Comment: can anyone help? Ive tried everything i know

Comment: i literally copy and pasted this code into a new class, extending activity too, just for testing and still doesnt work. can someone test this pls? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/4789/camera-and-gallery/12655/take-photo#t=201609161413543951207

Comment: A few basic debugging tips:
1) Add a few logging statements to each stage of your startup to ensure they're all running in the order you expect. If not, then there's a clue.
2) Include the logcat output from starting your app with the question

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your code is actually running as you expect, one possibility: `setPreviewSize(352, 288)` - that size may not be supported.

You'll need to check the list of supported preview sizes and pick one, or use 320,240 or 640,480 which are basically always available.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have added the necessary camera permission into AndroidManifest.xml file & if you are using marshmallow please check one more step that permission are enabled from setting=> Applications=> Application Manager=> Your App=> Permissions

Answer (score 0):

in XML android_height and android_width are 0, change it!